# Instagram auto like

Tags: javascript, console

Can someone help me fix this code? The purpose of this code is to like a post and then move to the next photo. I tried to run the code and the program doesn't like the post.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var heart = document.querySelector('button.coreSpriteHeartOpen');
    var arrow = document.querySelector('a.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow');
    if (heart) {
        heart.click();
        count++;
        console.log(`You've liked ${count} photo(s)`);
    }
    arrow.click();
}, 3000);
```

I tryed to use glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 as heart and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to run your code , and the problem was in the "count" declaration, this code works fine:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var count = 0;
  var heart = document.querySelector('button.coreSpriteHeartOpen');
  var arrow = document.querySelector('a.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow');
  if (heart) {
    heart.click();
    count++;
    console.log(`You've liked ${count} photo(s)`);
  }
  arrow.click();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let likes = 0;
setInterval(() => {
const heart = document.querySelector('svg[aria-label="Like"]').parentNode;
const arrow = document.querySelector('a.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow');
if (heart) {
    heart.click()
    likes++;
    console.log(`You've liked ${likes} post(s)`);
 }
 arrow.click();
 }, 5000);
```

Use this, it works.